# Results is not displayed when clicking submit button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to Android development and when I click the submit button, my results will not be displayed, instead just a blank results page appears. I am using a random generator so I want the results to be randomized each time the submit button is pressed. I have been trying to get it to work for hours so any help would be appreciated

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_system);
    final Random generator = new Random();
    correctResults = new String[] {"good job", "well done", "good"};

    RadioGroup gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.answer1A:
                ans1 = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.answer1B:
                ans1 = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    RadioGroup nutrition = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    nutrition.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.answer2A:
                ans2 = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.answer2B:
                ans2 = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    btnSubmitQuiz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    btnSubmitQuiz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // 1
            if (ans1 == 1 && ans2 == 1) {
                displayResult();
                getRandomCorrectResult();
            } else {
                displayResult();
            }
        }

        private void displayResult() {
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.system.SHOWRESULT");
            startActivity(i);
        }

        public String getRandomCorrectResult() {
            return correctResults[generator.nextInt(correctResults.length)];
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.system, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270677/how-to-randomize-if-statements-within-android-development)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise somebody answered it! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you could use this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) on how to start another activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this/context, SHOWRESULT.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and if you want to pass a value to another activity you need to use `intent.putExtra();`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this/context, SHOWRESULT.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");
```

and to retrieve those value to `SHOWRESULT activity` you can use bundles.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras == null) {
      //no data is passed
   }

   // get data via the key
   String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
   if (value1 != null) {
     // do something with the data
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues. First, you are sending an empty `Intent` to whatever activity you want to show...assuming you want to display the results in a separate activity, you will need to put some extras on that `Intent`...

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, SHOWRESULT.class);
i.putExtra("NAME", "VALUE");
startActivity(i);
```

and then receive the extras on the `Activity` you are starting...

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null)
   localVAriable = extras.getString("NAME");
```

The other issue you have is that the results are processed after you have started the other `Activity`

```
displayResult();
getRandomCorrectResult();
```

you should get the return value from `getRandomCorrectResult` and put them as extras in the intent...

```
String results = getRandomCorrectResult();
Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, SHOWRESULT.class);
i.putExtra("results", results);
startActivity(i);
```